# How do I install, what do I put as pathname?

Tags: linux, installation

I'm sure this is one of the dumbest problems asked on this site, but I am very new to linux, and a little out of my depths. I'm working off of this [tutorial](http://dti-tk.sourceforge.net/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Documentation.Install) and am stuck on the "add the path" and verify steps.

Problem **Unsolved**

For this one the tutorial told me to use this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:${DTITK_ROOT}/bin:${DTITK_ROOT}/utilities:${DTITK_ROOT}/scripts
```

I have already defined DTITK_ROOT, and have a few questions about the above instructions.

1. Should the ${} be left around the DTITK_ROOT?
2. My DTITK_ROOT is the full path (I think that's the right term) to the file I extracted the program to, should I change that?
3. What do I write for ${PATH} in that case? I understand that I'm supposed to replace it with something, but I don't know what. Everything I've tried doesn't pass the verify step.

I'm sorry if it seems like a dumb or really simple question, but I don't even know any keywords to google in order to find how to get the answer.